# Laravel get count of data using group-by with different name field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I understood how below query works.

```
$user_info = DB::table('usermetas')
                 ->select('browser', DB::raw('count(*) as total'),DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%h:%i %p') as day")
                 ->groupBy('browser')
                 ->get();
```

This will give result as

```
[{"browser":"GC","total":1,"day":"04:27 AM"},{"browser":"GC","total":2,"day":"04:27 AM"},
{"browser":"MF","total":1,"day":"05:27 AM"},
{"browser":"MF","total":1,"day":"07:27 AM"}]
```

Is it possible to obtain a result output as.

```
[{"browser":"GC","total":1,"day":"04:27 AM"},{"browser":"GC","total":2,"day":"04:27 AM"},
{"browser":"MF","total_test":1,"day":"05:27 AM"},
{"browser":"MF","total_test":1,"day":"07:27 AM"}]
```

can we give different name for count fields?

Comment: try this: DB::raw('count(browser) as total')

Comment: i want name as "total" for one browser and "total_test" for another browser. is it possible?